# how to call webservice from a different namespace in .net

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, web-services, namespaces

ok i'm in a bit of a pickle here.

When i try to call a webservice from a page that belongs  to **myproject.account.members** namespace

to a webservice that belongs to **myproject.services** i get an error

///-----modified: added error message-----///

```
---------------------------
Message from webpage
---------------------------
responseText=
textStatus=error
errorThrown=Unknown
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

eg.

The jquery ajax call from  **somepage.aspx** that belongs to **myproject.account.members**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Services/productService.asmx/getSomething") %>',
    data: '',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result){
        alert(result.d)
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){

alert("responseText=" + XMLHttpRequest.responseText + "\ntextStatus=" + textStatus + "\nerrorThrown=" + errorThrown);

    }
});
```

the webservice code belongs to **myproject.Services**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace myproject.Services
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for productService
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class productService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public String getSomething()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
    }
}
```

Basically if i change namespace of my webservice from **myproject.Services** to **myproject.account.member** it works if i call it from  a page that belongs  to myproject.account.members namespace... but it won't work if set the namespace to myproject.Services

please help.. how do i get around this? what if i want to call same service from several different namespaces within my project?`enter code here

Comment: "I get an error" doesn't give us enough detail. Please tell us what actually happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you changed the namespace of the code behind class of the web service don't forget to change it in the markup as well (`productService.asmx`):

```
<%@ WebService 
    Language="C#" 
    CodeBehind="productService.asmx.cs" 
    Class="myproject.Services.productService" %>
```

Also replace:

```
data: ''
```

with:

```
data: '{}'
```

And to get a more meaningful error message than the one you have posted in your question use FireBug or Chrome Developer tools in order to see the exact AJAX request that it being sent. You will see the request and the response from the server. It will help you better understand what is wrong with your code.

Comment: yes i was getting a different .net error... i did change it in the markup too... before the responsetext was the .net error page... now responsetext is blank, and textstatus=error

Comment: @robert, what is the exact response sent by the server that you see in FireBug? Normally it will contain the YSOD and the error message on it. Or maybe you get a 404? Only a developer toolbar will help you answer those questions and determine the exact cause of failure.

Comment: just realized... when changing the markup i put **myproject.Services** instead of **myproject.Services.productService** .... doh ... apologies.................. problem is solved!!!... the json data:'' part is a minor thing  i just took out the real data to make it simpler... i don't have a problem there

Comment: been going around this for hours just to have it solved in under 5 minutes...lol... ty Darin and stackoverflow rocks